# How To Install latest python version in dockerfile that include jenkins/jnlp-slave:latest

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I have issue with my dockerfile:
I tried to add latest python version (3.9 or 3.8) but when

My dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jnlp-slave:latest

USER root

ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ****************
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ***************
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION ***********
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT ************

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install vim nano expect sshpass curl apt-transport-https -y

**RUN apt install python3.9 -y**
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl4-gnutls-dev librtmp-dev
COPY pythonRequirements.txt pythonRequirements.txt
RUN mkdir ~/.aws/ && touch ~/.aws/config

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y tcpdump
RUN apt-get install jq -y
RUN apt-get install -y pkg-config
RUN apt install libcairo2-dev -y
RUN pip3 install -r pythonRequirements.txt --no-cache-dir
RUN apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev python3-tk

RUN curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y kubectl
RUN mkdir ~/.kube
RUN apt-get  install xvfb -y
RUN pip3 install psycopg2-binary


RUN aws s3 cp s3://*************************
RUN aws s3 cp s3://*************************
RUN aws s3 cp s3://*************************
RUN aws s3 cp s3://*************************
```

When I tried it and then I checked the python version I got python 3.5!!!

**My docker file must include FROM jenkins/jnlp-slave:latest**

Comment: You can use something like pyenv to compile a newer version

Comment: @jordanm before anything I need a way to install python3.9 into my docker file, after then I will use pyenv

Comment: Would it be easier to use the [Jenkins Docker support](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) to run builds inside containers with tools?  Then you could, for example, do your build `docker.image('python:3.9').inside { ... }` instead of trying to get the tools on to every build system.